# How to Redirect with POST method and headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, post, header

[API description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQZD9.png) I need to redirect to an API using c#, but I need to use POST method and add some headers to it.
I know Redirect function uses GET method and you can use the POST method by html form but with html form I can't add headers. So is ajax call the only way to do this? And if so, can you give me a sample code on how to achieve this on codebehind c#?

I tried something like that but I keep getting an error of input string not in correct format for the ajax call string.

```
if (Request["code"] != null)
        {
            string AuthCode = Request["code"];
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientID}:{clientSecret}");
            var clientAuthHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();

            string url = "https://sandbox-oauth.hellenicbank.com/token/exchange?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&code=" + AuthCode;
            string ajaxCall = "$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '" + url + "', " +
            "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', " +
            "data: '', " +
            "dataType: 'json', " +
            "beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '" + clientAuthHeader.ToString() + "');}, " +
            "});";

            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append("<html>");
            s.Append("<head>");
            s.AppendFormat("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>");
            s.Append("</head>");
            s.Append("<body>");
            s.Append("<script>");
            s.AppendFormat(ajaxCall);
            s.Append("</script></form></body></html>");
            response.Write(s.ToString());
            response.End();
            return;
        }
```

Edit: I tried the POST request in c# with the following code. Apparently, I must be doing something wrong cause I'm not getting an exception nor a json.

```
public async Task<JObject> ExhcangeToken(string header, string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + header);
        
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                JObject adResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseContent);
                return adResponse;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            Json = webException.ToString();
            if (webException.Response != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webException.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseContent); ;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

EDIT: Ok, so i changed the request code and tried with RestSharp this time and finally, I got a response. The problem is that i get a 404 not found error.
This is the new code:

```
if (Request["code"] != null)
        {
            string AuthCode = Request["code"];
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientID}:{clientSecret}");
            var clientAuthHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            string url = "https://sandbox-oauth.hellenicbank.com/token/exchange?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&code=" + AuthCode;
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", clientAuthHeader.ToString());
            request.Parameters.Clear();

            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

            var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
            return;
        }
```

I tried calling the API from https://reqbin.com/ with the same url im using in my code and it works fine. So, im guessing the problem must be with the authentication header im using. In the API description asks for
[Headers] Authorization: Basic Base64Encode(YOUR_CLIENT_ID:YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET).
Am I adding this header the correct way?

[This is the JSON response im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvg83.png)

EDIT: Solved it. I made the authentication like this:

```
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientID, clientSecret);
```

It worked. I finally got the access token. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: `and the only way to use the POST method is by html form` Who told you that?

Comment: It's not clear. Are you saying you need to use C# to generate some JavaScript, which will then call this API via AJAX? Or are you saying that C# itself needs to call the API? Because C# (and most other programming languages) can make HTTP requests, no problem. I can't help feeling that you don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I suspect you ought to be making this request from your C#, because it would probably be a **very** bad idea to expose the authorisation code in the Javascript of your web page (because any user can go and read the Javascript source code, but not the C# code). Maybe the API provider has some examples you can follow, though.

Comment: I know that you can make POST reuqests with c# but i need to use redirect while posting data. I couldn't find a way to use c# redirect with post method by adding headers to it as well.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "i need to use redirect". Please describe _precisely_ what you want to happen after the POST request has completed. Details are important.

Comment: Even better, give us a link to the actual full API documentation, instead of just a picture of a small part of it. Then we can see for ourselves what you are supposed to do in this situation.

Comment: Actually I found it already at https://openbanking.hellenicbank.com/ - and for this request it says afterwards `After successfully submitting the exchange token, this request will return a JSON object containing the access token` ...so it just returns JSON. There is no need for any redirecting. According to the instructions, this request should be happening _after_ the redirect (which was the result of the initial request to get the authorization code). So...you can just make this request from C# and get the JSON response in a normal way, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have you used the debugger to stop the code and examine the contents of `responseContent`? a breakpoint on the line following both your `string responseContent = ` lines would make sense.

Comment: Also you should cast your WebResponse as HttpWebResponse then you can get the status code. (Or, I recommend, ditch this code and use HttpClient or even RestSharp to make your API life easier and less verbose.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked by using RestSharp

Final code:

```
if (Request["code"] != null)
        {
            string AuthCode = Request["code"];

            string url = "https://sandbox-oauth.hellenicbank.com/token/exchange?grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&code=" + AuthCode;
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(clientID, clientSecret);
            request.Parameters.Clear();

            request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

            var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
            return;
        }
```